# ActiveRecord in where condition > and >= are the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am currently using ActiveRecord to access a PostGres DB.

The overall app works but I have some issue when trying to get the data from a specific timezone.

I am trying to get data since X to today.

I have user the where condition as below:

```
    time = [ "ts > :since_date", since_date: params['since']]
```

This returning the list of data from "since_date" to the last one.

My issue is I do not want the 'since_date' as a part of the result but everything > to since_date. I have tried to play with '>=' and '>' only. 
In both cases, I have the same result.

Any idea how to not have the 'since_date' as a part of the result

Right now the ts field is always following the format :

```
2017-08-24 07:00:21.967185+00
```

et the param['since'] will follow exactly the same format :

```
2017-08-24 07:00:21.967185+00
```

which mean when I am doing the where condition with since using the command

```
time = [ "ts > :since_date", since_date: params['since']]
```

must return from '2017-08-24 07:00:21.967185+00' to now but the data with ts = '2017-08-24 07:00:21.967185+00' must not be returned that's why I have used > instead of >=

Thanks

Comment: Is `ts` a timestamp and `since` is a string-formatted date (i.e. "2017-01-01")? If so, it may be casting your date to a timestamp (at 00:00:00), which would include everything from that timestamp forward.

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge the string is formated as "2017-08-24 07:00:21.967185+00"

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge I reuse the exact same format than the one received

Comment: is that string the value of `ts` or `params[:since]`?

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge params[:since]

Comment: Can you update your question with some example values for the `ts` column?

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge done